# Query builder instance of multiple values

Tags: php, doctrine, instanceof

How can I update my query in order to check the instance of in an array of possible values?

For my example below I would like to select the posts that have the author instances of either UserType or AdminType:

```
$qb->select('post')
    ->from('Posts\Entity\Post','post')        
    ->where('post.author INSTANCE OF '.UserType::class);
```

Comment: It's hard to answer that without knowing how your DB and Entities are designed. Do You use SingleTableInheritance for UserType/AdminType here? Then the table must define a distcriminator column, which you should be able to test against the user-type. See https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.17/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance